# Consulta sql en php con variable de fecha actual

Tags: php, mysql, date, sql

La consulta inicial fue resulta. Gracias!! Aprovecho para realizar 3 consultar sobre este mismo codigo
cuando me devuelve 'Saldo' me coloca 5 decimales por eje "1977.87000" y necesitaría que solo exponga 2 decimales, es decir "1977.87"
como le agrego el símbolo "$" a 'Saldo'?
por otro lado necesito que exponga el total de todos las filas de 'Saldo' como debo hacerlo?
De nuevo muchas gracias

```
<?php

$ServerName = "miserver";
$Username = "usuario";
$Password = "pass";
$NameBD = "nombreBD";

$conexion = new mysqli($ServerName, $Username, $Password, $NameBD);
mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

if ($conexion->connect_error) {
    die("Ha fallado la conexión: " . $conexion->connect_error);
}

//echo "Conectado correctamente";

  $fechaActual = date('d-m-y');

$consulta= "SELECT SUM(CtaCte.Debe - CtaCte.Haber) AS Saldo  ,f.NroInterno AS IdFactura, f.Boca,  f.Tipo,  f.Letra,  f.Numero, f.Fecha, f.Moneda, f.Obs, f.MonedaCotizacion  FROM Facturas f, CtaCte WHERE f.IdCliente = CtaCte.IdCliente AND (CtaCte.IdFactura = f.NroInterno OR CtaCte.IdFactura2 = f.NroInterno) AND CtaCte.IdCliente = 422 AND f.Tipo IN (1, 2, 0, 7) AND f.Empresa = 1 AND CtaCte.Empresa = 1 AND f.Sucursal = 2 AND CtaCte.Sucursal = 2 AND (IsNull(CtaCte.Conciliado) OR CtaCte.Conciliado='N' OR CtaCte.Conciliado='')  AND NOT f.Anulada = 'S' AND NOT CtaCte.Anulado = 'S' AND CtaCte.Fecha <= DateValue ('14/02/2020') AND (f.Pagada = 'N' OR IsNull(Pagada))  GROUP BY f.NroInterno, f.Boca,  f.Tipo,  f.Letra,  f.Numero, f.Moneda, f.MonedaCotizacion, f.Obs, f.Fecha  ORDER BY f.Fecha, f.Letra, f.Boca, f.Numero";
$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);

?>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.Estilo1 {
    font-family: Calibri;
    font-weight: bold;
}
-->
</style>

<div>
    <div align="center">
      <table border="1">
        <thead>
          <td><div align="center" class="Estilo1">BOCA</div></td>
          <td><div align="center" class="Estilo1">FACTURA</div></td>
          <td><div align="center" class="Estilo1">LETRA</div></td>
            <td><div align="center" class="Estilo1">FECHA EMISION</div></td>
            <td><div align="center" class="Estilo1">OBSERVACIONES</div></td>
            <td><div align="center" class="Estilo1">SALDO PENDIENTE</div></td>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

<?php
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado))
{
?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo ($fila['Boca'] );?></td>
                <td><?php echo ($fila['Numero'] );?></td>
                <td><?php echo ($fila['Letra'] );?></td>
                <td><?php echo date("d.m.y", strtotime($fila['Fecha']));?></td>
                <td><?php echo ($fila['Obs']);?></td>
                <td><?php echo ($fila['Saldo']);?></td>
                  </tr>
  <?php
}
echo $fechaActual;
?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Podrías colocar el código PHP de lo que has intentado, para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Has probado con lo siguiente? $fechaActual = date('d-m-Y');

Comment: Hola puedes usar esta idea: `$hoy = getdate();` y luego formateas teniendo en cuenta que $hoy puede manejarse como array y empleas las claves "year", "mon" y "mday" para obtener los números de año, mes y día del mes (respectivamente) y luego concatenarlos con separador '/'. Ten presente que getdate() te entrega la fecha del servidor, que puede no ser la pactada comercialmente.

Comment: Otra opción es cambiar para utilizar la función `CURRENT_DATE()`: Por ejemplo, así: `... AND CtaCte.Fecha <= CURRENT_DATE() ... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función `CURRENT_DATE()`:

Por ejemplo, así:

```
... AND CtaCte.Fecha <= CURRENT_DATE() ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Podes resolverlo solamente utilizando SQL, podés obtener la fecha del momento con CURRENT_DATE(), modificando tu query así:

```
AND CtaCte.Fecha <= CURRENT_DATE()
```

Saludos.

Comment: Pregunta: qué sentido tiene editar una respuesta para dejarla igual a otra existente? :-P